# What is the most straightforward GWT workaround for same origin policy restriction (trying to query google maps api)?

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, gwt, same-origin-policy

I am trying to do some basic geocoding using the google maps API and a GWT dyanmic web project in Eclipse.  For example, query the following URL:

http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA&output=json&sensor=false

and get back the data for parsing.  I am running into some confusion about whether it is better to set up a proxy or somehow use JSON with javascript (the 2 answers that I've come across to tutorials for).  I have not been able to get either method working -- so I'm looking for some guidance.  Thanks for your help in advance --

-Andrew

Comment: That api looks like it supports JSONP too. Just add `&callback=` (eg http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA&output=json&sensor=false&callback=foo) and BOOM goes the same-origin-policy.

Comment: Do I have to use javascript to achieve this?  I'm currently trying to use a RequestBuilder to do it and setting a RequestCallback object.  Here's my code within onModuleLoad() (CypalStudio GWT Eclipse project):

String url = new String("http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA&output=json&sensor=false&key=&callback=");
  RequestCallback foo = new RequestCallback(){
   public void onResponseReceived(Request request, Response response) {
    if (STATUS_CODE_OK == response.getStatusCode()) {
         Window.alert("Response OK! : " + response.getText());
    }

Comment: else {
        Window.alert("Non-200 status code " + response.getStatusCode());
      }
    }

  public void onError(Request request, Throwable exception) {
  }
 };
     RequestBuilder builder = new RequestBuilder(RequestBuilder.GET, url);
  builder.setCallback(foo);
  try{
   Request response = builder.sendRequest(null, foo);
  }
  catch(RequestException e){
   Window.alert("Exception! : " + e.getMessage());
  }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just use the [GWT Maps API](http://code.google.com/docreader/#p=gwt-google-apis&s=gwt-google-apis&t=MapsGettingStarted)? I think you can use the [Geocoder](http://gwt-google-apis.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/maps/1.0/com/google/gwt/maps/client/geocode/Geocoder.html) class to do what you want.

Comment: @Andrew C: it is polite on SO to accept the answer most helpful to you by clicking the big checkbox to the left of this question.

Comment: Woops, meant "*the* question" ;)